# Android EditText .setText("") not working

Tags: android, settext

I am trying to clear the text in my edit text field but for some reason it is not working.

I have declared an edit text field in the xml of my view:

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/enterGlucoseLevel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mySimpleXYPlot"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
```

I have used the attribute onClick to link my button to the enterGlucoseAction() method in my MainActivity class:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/enterGlucoseButton"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick= "enterGlucoseAction"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/enterGlucoseLevel"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/enterGlucoseLvlButton" />
```

Here is that method:

```
public void enterGlucoseAction(View v) {
    glucoseField.setText("");

     Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "You clicked the button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

I get the toast pop up but my edit text field is not being cleared.

Here is my on create and instance variables in case the problem lies there.

```
private XYPlot plot;
private Button addGlucoseLevel;
private EditText glucoseField;
private XYSeries currentSeries;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    addGlucoseLevel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.enterGlucoseButton);
    glucoseField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterGlucoseLevel);                     

    currentSeries = new SimpleXYSeries(Arrays.asList(new Number[] { 7200, 8, 54000, 2, 64800, 4 }), 
            SimpleXYSeries.ArrayFormat.XY_VALS_INTERLEAVED,
            "Glucose Level");

    //Create an series of numbers to plot.
    createGraph(currentSeries);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

And sorry, I know this has been asked before but I can't find a solution to my problem specifically.

Answer (score 3):

To clear your `EditText` which accepts numbers use `clear()` method:

```
glucoseField.getText().clear();
```

You can try setting it this way:

```
((EditText)findViewById(R.id.enterGlucoseLevel)).getText().clear();
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it still didn't work.

Comment: @Programmer Are you able to change this `EditText` 's content programatically? And are you sure you don't have more views with the same id (`enterGlucoseLevel`)?

Comment: I'm sure there are no name conflicts. And I don't seem to be able to change its content programmatically, I added a   glucoseField.setText("23423"); in the onCreate and I see nothing when I run it.

Must be a problem with storing (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterGlucoseLevel);  in an instance variable?

Comment: @Programmer Are you able to input text there manually? Maybe your text color is the same as background so you cannot see any content? Can you post full content of `activity_main`? Do you manipulate this text view from other methods?

Comment: Nope, I can enter stuff in there in the emulator  :/

Comment: @Programmer You mean you can or you cannot?

Comment: @Programmer please try this: `((EditText)findViewById(R.id.enterGlucoseLevel)).getText().clear();`

Comment: Yes! works. Must be an issue with storing it in an instance variable, or maybe because it's private. 

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use `getText().clear();` just replace `glucoseField.setText("");` with `glucoseField.getText().clear();`

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
setText("\b");
```

As we can use escape sequence

Comment: No idea what this does or why I'd need to escape anything. Tried it anyway. Didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
((EditText)findViewById(R.id.yourEditTextId)).getText().clear();
```

anything else crashed.